# Call element of object with prefix

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an application in Swift and I have one file ToursObject.swift with that on it :

```
import Foundation

class ToursObject {

    var nameFr: String!;
    var nameEn: String!;
    var nameEs: String!;
    var nameIt: String!;

    init(json: NSDictionary) {

        self.nameFr = json["name_fr"] as? String;
        self.nameEn = json["name_en"] as? String;
        self.nameEs = json["name_es"] as? String;
        self.nameIt = json["name_it"] as? String;

    }

}
```

In my tableViewController i have this code :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // custom cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("toursCellReuseIdentifier") as! ToursTableViewCell;

    // here i get the actual preferredLanguage from previous screen which propose en, fr, it and es
    let codeCountry = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0] as String;
    // if we print we will have En, Fr, It or Es for codeCountry

    // I want do something like that but of course when i build I have this error message from xCode : Value of type 'ToursObject" has no member 'name'
    cell.titleLabel.text = (self.arrayOfAvailableToursObject[indexPath.item].name+codeCountry);
    // work correctly because no concatenation on the name of member
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = (self.arrayOfAvailableToursObject[indexPath.item].nameEn);

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is this line because i don't know how to make a concatenation to call the good key of my dictionary :

```
cell.titleLabel.text = (self.arrayOfAvailableToursObject[indexPath.item].name+codeCountry);
```

I think it's not possible to do like i want but there is another solution ?

In advance thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is you need to access things dynamically by language? In that case you are making more work for yourself by deserializing the JSON into object with concrete properties. Why not keep it dynamic?

```
class ToursObject {

    var nameForCountry: [String:String]!;

    init(json: NSDictionary) {

        self.nameForCountry = // deserialize into your typed dictionary;

    }

}
```

You can then access as follows:

```
cell.titleLabel.text =     
     self.arrayOfAvailableToursObject.nameForCountry[codeCountry]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thank you for help ColinE it's work now,

to complete your answer with example for those who need to know how it was resolved you can find below explanations for my case :

In my file ToursObject.swift I changed it to :

```
    class ToursObject {

        var nameForCountry: [String:String]!;

        init(json: NSDictionary) {

            // array of strings for one special key with selectedLanguage
            self.nameForCountry = ["fr":(json["name_fr"] as? String)!, "en":(json["name_en"] as? String)!, "es":(json["name_es"] as? String)!, "it":(json["name_it"] as? String)!];
        }
   }
```

And in my tableViewController i call the appropriate language like that now

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // custom cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("toursCellReuseIdentifier") as! ToursTableViewCell;

        // here i get the actual preferredLanguage string from previous screen which propose "en", "fr", "it" and "es"
        let codeCountry = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0] as String;

        // Configure labels of cell with appropriate language
        cell.titleLabel.text = (self.arrayOfAvailableToursObject[indexPath.item].nameForCountry[codeCountry]);

        return cell;
    }
```

Hope these answers will be helpful.

Many thanks,